# Difference between two Rooting methods

Tags: rooting, 4.2-jelly-bean

I bought a new XOLO Q700 last week, with Android jelly bean 4.2.1

I found out two ways to root the phone.

**First**, as per the instructions given in this website

[[ROOT] Xolo Q700 Rooted before it hits the shelves!](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2273069)

> **As quoted in the website...**
>
> The process is really simple for rooting the phone:
>
> - First what you need to do is download "MotoChopper" on your PC.
> - Extract the .zip file  to a specific folder Install the USB drivers      using PdaNet+
> - Enable USB Debugging mode on your device.
> - For Windows  users, execute the "run.bat" inside the contents of the    extracted    archive. Be sure to run it as admin.
> - For Linux or OS X users, execute “./run.sh” via terminal window.
>
> And its done! I have tested this method on windows and it is working.
>   It will continuously repeat that adb server is outdated and it is
>   killing it but don't worry about it, it will still continue...
>
> Follow the steps carefully in the terminal window. After the window
>   closes itself REBOOT YOUR PHONE!!!
>
> To check if the phone is rooted correctly or not use, Root Checker
>   Basic from the playstore, it should do your work

**Second**, is using the software [UnlockRoot](http://www.unlockroot.com/unlockroot.html)

> Though the second method is pretty simple, connect your phone and hit
>   ROOT and UNROOT to revert

While the First method is a little more tedious.

So I would like to know what is the difference between  the two methods. Also which would be safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the motochopper exploit from the first thread. The exploit is from Dan Rosenberg ([djrbliss](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=4229979) on XDA), a known security researcher who has published some Android root exploits so far.

If the exploit doesn't work, there's no harm it can inflict. If it does work, harm can only be done while persisting the root access but I haven't seen any problems with that (either it doesn't work at all or it just works). The second alternative seems to be a streamlined free/paid service that's probably probing your device and it will eventually use the same motochopper exploit from the first thread.

Background info:

- Announcement on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=40746664#post40746664)
- Exploit: http://vulnfactory.org/public/motochopper.zip

Answer (score 1):

Since both sets of instructions you link to consist of running some closed-source software that interacts with your phone through the debug interface, only the authors of those programs can tell you precisely what they do.

As ce4 says in his comment, the one on the XDA-Developers website exploits a *vulnerability*: that is, a defect in the phone's software. The defect lets a program run as root on the phone, and this software uses that to install a program permanently so that it always runs as root.

The other software could be doing anything. If it works for your phone, it probably exploits the same vulnerability, but only the author can tell you for sure.